# How can I disable all component and change background color?

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

I have a WPF application. When I press the exit button, I want to see the box like this:

[image]

The box name is Risultati. This works, but I want the all WPF application is disable and I can see a light gray how the modal dialog.

This is the code that I use to create my box, Risutlati:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ContattoOculare.RiepilogoEsercizio"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="342" d:DesignWidth="520">
    <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0" Height="342" Width="520">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="80" />
            <RowDefinition Height="35" />
            <RowDefinition Height="40" />
            <RowDefinition Height="100" />
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush x:Name="backgroudCarta" ImageSource="./Resources/Esci_dal_gioco_Maschera.png"/>
        </Grid.Background>

        <!--INTESTAZIONE-->
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,20,0,0" >
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                <RowDefinition Height="32" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                <Label Content="Risultati" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                   FontSize="30"  FontFamily="./Font/#Roboto-Bold" Foreground="White"/>
            </Grid>
            <Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,0,14">
                <Label Content="Contatto Oculare" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
               FontSize="18" FontFamily="./Font/#Roboto-Bold" Foreground="White" Margin="190,-12,184,0"/>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <!--FINE INTESTAZIONE-->

        <!--PRIMA RIGA-->
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <Label Content="Tempo"  FontSize="22"
               FontFamily="./Font/#Roboto-Bold" Foreground="Gray" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Grid>
        <!--FINE PRIMA RIGA-->

        <!--SECONDA RIGA-->
        <Grid Grid.Row="2" Margin="0,-12,0,0">
            <Label x:Name="labelTempo" Content="0 sec"  FontSize="25" FontWeight="Bold"
               FontFamily="./Font/#Roboto-Bold" Foreground="Gray" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Grid>
        <!--FINE SECONDA RIGA-->

        <!--TERZA RIGA-->
        <Grid Grid.Row="3" Margin="50,0,50,0">
            <TextBox x:Name="textDescrizione" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="25"
               FontFamily="Calibri" Foreground="Gray"
               TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" Height="100" />
        </Grid>
        <!--FINE TERZA RIGA-->

        <!--QUARTA RIGA-->
        <Grid Grid.Row="4" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,5,0,0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid Height="Auto" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                     Grid.Column="0" >
                <Image Width="206" Height="46"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                            x:Name="save">
                <Image.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                            <Setter Property="Source" Value="./Resources/Tasto_Uscita gioco_Salva_Roll_ON.png"/>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Source" Value="./Resources/Tasto_Uscita_gioco_Roll_OFF.png"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Image.Style>
                </Image>
                <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Roboto-Bold"
                           FontSize="20" Foreground="White">Salva</Label>
            </Grid>

            <Grid Height="Auto" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                     Grid.Column="1" >
                <Image Width="206" Height="46"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                            x:Name="stop">
                    <Image.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                            <Setter Property="Source" Value="./Resources/Tasto_Uscita_gioco_Salva_Roll_OFF.png"/>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="./Resources/Tasto_Uscita_gioco_Roll_OFF.png"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Image.Style>
                </Image>
                <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Roboto-Bold"
                           FontSize="20" Foreground="White">Annulla</Label>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <!--FINE QUARTA RIGA-->
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: "I want the all WPF application is disable and I can see a light gray how the modal dialog." You should really rephrase this; it's unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any WPF window, I normally will implement a mask over its content, something like:

```
<Window>
    <Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibility"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid>
            <!--your window content-->
        </Grid> 

        <!--this is your mask, give it a semi-transparent color-->
        <Grid Background="#65000000" Visibility="{Binding IsModalDialogActived, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibility}}"/>

         <Grid>
            <!--your dialog-->
        </Grid> 
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

So that you can set the mask to Visible when your show the modal dialogue, and the mask will cast a shadow over the interface and prevent any user interactions with your application.

Comment: Ok, I don't understand how can I from code set the valu of IsModalDialogActived

Comment: @bircastri, When you showing your Risutlati box, just set `IsModalDialogActived` to `true`?

Comment: I'm use your code, and the code works but, also the my dialog is under the grid and this is not good. I'm try to set Pnal.ZIndex=1 for grid and Panel.ZIndex=100 for the dialog, but it not works

Comment: @bircastri, what's your XAML structure? You can put your dialog below the mask Gird.. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would extend the Window class rather than the UserControl class. Then, call ShowDialog to show up your box. All other windows in the application will be disabled. That's a true (WPF) modal dialog, loosely coupled and reusable across your application.

Keep in mind:

- Use AllowsTransparency="True" to allow semi-transparent colors for the Background.
- Use WindowStyle="None" to remove the borders.
- Use WindowState="Maximized" to occupy all available space.
- Set the HorizontalAlignment, VerticalAlignment, Width, Height and Margin properties in your main Grid to place your box where desired.